# Conditional statement: change one variable in a data list based on certain input

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Can I use conditional statement to change one variable in a data list based on certain input?

For instance, a data list as follows. I need `d = perd` or `phyd` when I use different input: `dlist[x]`, `d=perd`; `dlist[y]`, `d=phyd`. x and y can be anything, what I need is just to give an order and then make it as perd or phyd.

```
    dlist <- list(
      Nsubjects = 1,
      Ntrials = 2,
      d = perd,
    )

perd <- c (1,2,3)
phyd <- c (4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create another list with names to store `perd` and `phyd` ?

```
plist <- list(x = c (1,2,3),  y = c (4,5,6))
```

You can then extract the data from it by it's name.

```
val <- 'x'

dlist <- list(
  Nsubjects = 1,
  Ntrials = 2,
  d = plist[[val]]
)
```

---

Without creating `plist` you can do. :

```
list(
  Nsubjects = 1,
  Ntrials = 2,
  d = if(val == 1) c(1,2,3) else c(4,5,6)
)
```

Or also :

```
list(
  Nsubjects = 1,
  Ntrials = 2,
  d = list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))[[val]]
)
```

where `val <- 1` or 2.

Comment: can I do something like `dlist [d=plist[[val]]]`? As my purpose is to put data list into JAGS and without creating two separate data lists.

Comment: Actually initially I was thinking `list(Nsubjects = 1,Ntrials = 2,d = if(val == 1) c (1,2,3) else c(4,5,6))` where `val = 1` or 2. This way you don't need secondary list `plist`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Sorry this might be a stupid question. I did this:  `d = if(val ==1) perd else phyd` where I already created `perd` and `phyd` and I got this error message:  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. I defined `val` as `val <- c (1,2)`

Comment: I though `val` will only have 1 value at a given time. If it has more than one value then you need to use `d = list(perd,phyd)[val]`

Comment: I am a bit confused. If I defined `val` as `val <-1`, I would have a data list with `perd` when I put `dlist[[val==1]]`, what if I want a list with `phyd`? If I put `dlist[[val==2]]` do I need to define `val <- c (1,2)` ?

Comment: Can I call the separate data lists by `dlist[val==1]` and `dlist[val==2]`

Comment: Keep my answer as it is with `d = if(val == 1) c(1,2,3) else c(4,5,6)` or `d = list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))[[val]]`. If `val` is a single number it will work as it is. If it is length more than 1 use `lapply` i.e `lapply(c(1, 2), function(x) list(Nsubjects = 1,Ntrials = 2,d = list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))[[x]]))`